# teamview won't open on Mac

Tags: osx-elcapitan, teamviewer

suddenly my Mac's TeamViewer seems to have disappeared so i'm trying to download and install another version, for personal use. Mac is El Capitan/10.11.6, TeamViewer is v13. I install TeamViewer then try to start it, and the Apple>About this Mac>System Report>Logs shows this message:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “TeamViewer.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."
```

Yet the TeamViewer icon is in the icon tray as running. My terminal "top" shows TeamViewer process running as PID 773. Any ideas how to get TeamViewer to open?

Here is part of the log file - whole thing is too large to paste, but this has some of the TeamViewers msgs:

Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/TeamViewer/Install%20TeamViewer.pkg#AuthPluginPackage.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/0295EADB-C0FD-477A-A771-A0EB7BDB1316.activeSandbox/Root/Library/Security/SecurityAgentPlugins, uid=0)
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: efw_cache_update Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app exited with 251
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: prevent user idle system sleep
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: suspending backupd
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Executing script "./preinstall" in /private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.G3pm9U/Scripts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12Agent.bqFYqV
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ pathToFlag=/tmp/tvserviceEnabled
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ pathToOnlyStartServiceAfterInstallFlag=/tmp/tvonlystartservice
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ pathToDesktopPath=/tmp/tvDesktopPath
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ pathToGUIPath=/tmp/tvGUIPath
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ pathToAppPath=/tmp/tvPath
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ pathToInstallerFlag=/tmp/tvinstallerrunning
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ servicePlist=/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ servicePlistTemp=/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service_temp
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ desktopPlist=/Library/LaunchAgents/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_desktop
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ guiPlist=/Library/LaunchAgents/com.teamviewer.teamviewer
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ restarterPlist=/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_restarter
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ restarterScript=/tmp/restarter
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ deviceManagementPlists='/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.teamviewer*'
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ migrationPrefix=migrate_
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ migrationTargetDirectory=/tmp
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ touch /tmp/tvinstallerrunning
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: + saveAgentState
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: + '[' -e /tmp/tvserviceEnabled ']'
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: + '[' -e /tmp/.TeamViewer.lock ']'
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ ps -A
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ grep TeamViewer_Service
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ grep .app
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: ++ awk '{print $1}'
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: + servicePid=
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: + '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./preinstall: + exit 0
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Using trashcan path /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/PKInstallSandboxTrash/0295EADB-C0FD-477A-A771-A0EB7BDB1316.sandboxTrash for sandbox /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/0295EADB-C0FD-477A-A771-A0EB7BDB1316.activeSandbox
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Shoving /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/0295EADB-C0FD-477A-A771-A0EB7BDB1316.activeSandbox/Root (3 items) to /
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Executing script "./postinstall" in /private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.G3pm9U/Scripts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12.5MFglL
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Executing script "./postinstall" in /private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.G3pm9U/Scripts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12Agent.bqFYqV
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ pathToFlag=/tmp/tvserviceEnabled
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ pathToOnlyStartServiceAfterInstallFlag=/tmp/tvonlystartservice
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ pathToDesktopPath=/tmp/tvDesktopPath
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ pathToGUIPath=/tmp/tvGUIPath
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ pathToAppPath=/tmp/tvPath
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ pathToInstallerFlag=/tmp/tvinstallerrunning
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ servicePlist=/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ servicePlistTemp=/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service_temp
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ desktopPlist=/Library/LaunchAgents/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_desktop
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ guiPlist=/Library/LaunchAgents/com.teamviewer.teamviewer
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ restarterPlist=/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_restarter
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ restarterScript=/tmp/restarter
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ deviceManagementPlists='/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.teamviewer*'
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ migrationPrefix=migrate_
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ migrationTargetDirectory=/tmp
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ touch /tmp/tvinstallerrunning
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.Helper.plist
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.Helper.plist: service already loaded
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + appName=TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + moveApp TeamViewer.app '/Volumes/TeamViewer/Install TeamViewer.pkg'
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local __appName=TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local '__pkgPath=/Volumes/TeamViewer/Install TeamViewer.pkg'
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /tmp/tvPath ']'
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + appFolderPath=/Applications
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + destFolder=/Applications
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ basename /Applications
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + destFolderName=Applications
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' Applications == 'TeamViewer 8' ']'
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' Applications == 'TeamViewer 9' ']'
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app ']'
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + appPath=/Applications/TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:53 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ xattr -p com.TeamViewer.ConfigurationId /Applications/TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: xattr: /Applications/TeamViewer.app: No such xattr: com.TeamViewer.ConfigurationId
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local __oldConfigId=
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + saveReplace /Applications/TeamViewer.app /Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local __OLD=/Applications/TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local __NEW=/Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ dirname /Applications/TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + oldDir=/Applications
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ basename /Applications/TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + oldFile=TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + mkdir -p /Applications
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + tempFoldeName=/Applications/old_TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /Applications/TeamViewer.app ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + mv /Applications/TeamViewer.app /Applications/old_TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + mv /Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app /Applications/TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /Applications/old_TeamViewer.app ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + rm -rf /Applications/old_TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + rm -rf /Applications/.TeamViewer
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + customConfigurationFileName '/Volumes/TeamViewer/Install TeamViewer.pkg' /Applications/TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local '__pkgPath=/Volumes/TeamViewer/Install TeamViewer.pkg'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local __appPath=/Applications/TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local __pkgFolder=/Volumes/TeamViewer
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local '__configPattern=/Volumes/TeamViewer/*-idc*'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ wc -l
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ ls '/Volumes/TeamViewer/*-idc*'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ tr -d ' '
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local __fileCount=0
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: ++ xattr -p com.TeamViewer.ConfigurationId /Applications/TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: xattr: /Applications/TeamViewer.app: No such xattr: com.TeamViewer.ConfigurationId
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local __newConfigId=
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' '' == '' ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + restoreAgentState
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service_temp.plist
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + chmod 644 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.teamviewer.teamviewer.plist
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + chmod 644 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_desktop.plist
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /tmp/tvserviceEnabled ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + mv /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service_temp.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service.plist
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + migrateDeviceManagementSettings
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + for filePath in '${deviceManagementPlists}'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e '/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.teamviewer*' ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + stopAgents
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local __appPattern=
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /tmp/tvserviceEnabled ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + osascript -e 'tell application "TeamViewer" to quit'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + restartService TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + local __appName=TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /tmp/tvserviceEnabled ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /tmp/tvonlystartservice ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + rm -f /tmp/restarter
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + rm -f /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_restarter.plist
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' '!' -e /tmp/tvPath ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "/Applications/TeamViewer.app"'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + cleanup
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /tmp/tvinstallerrunning ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + rm -f /tmp/tvinstallerrunning
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /tmp/tvserviceEnabled ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /tmp/tvPath ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + '[' -e /Applications/.TeamViewer ']'
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: ./postinstall: + exit 0
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Writing receipt for com.teamviewer.teamviewer12PriviledgedHelper to /
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Writing receipt for com.teamviewer.teamviewer12 to /
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Writing receipt for com.teamviewer.teamviewer12Font to /
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Writing receipt for com.teamviewer.teamviewer12Agent to /
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Writing receipt for com.teamviewer.teamviewer12Restarter to /
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Writing receipt for com.teamviewer.teamviewer12AuthPlugin to /
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Touched bundle /Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Touched bundle /Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Touched bundle /Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app/Contents/Frameworks/TVNoteIntegration.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TeamViewer Note.app
Mar 12 13:05:54 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: Installed "TeamViewer" (12.0.82953)
Mar 12 13:05:55 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: releasing backupd
Mar 12 13:05:55 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: allow user idle system sleep
Mar 12 13:05:55 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: ----- End install -----
Mar 12 13:05:55 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: 3.2s elapsed install time
Mar 12 13:05:55 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Running idle tasks
Mar 12 13:05:55 Davids-MacBook-Pro Installer[904]: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “TeamViewer.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc18a601520 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Mar 12 13:05:55 Davids-MacBook-Pro Installer[904]: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Autoupdate.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc18bb00090 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Mar 12 13:05:55 Davids-MacBook-Pro Installer[904]: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app/Contents/Frameworks/TVNoteIntegration.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TeamViewer%20Note.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “TeamViewer Note.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app/Contents/Frameworks/TVNoteIntegration.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TeamViewer%20Note.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/.TeamViewer/TeamViewer.app/Contents/Frameworks/TVNoteIntegration.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TeamViewer Note.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc18bc7f780 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Mar 12 13:05:55 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Removing client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=904, uid=501 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer)
Mar 12 13:05:55 Davids-MacBook-Pro installd[335]: PackageKit: Done with sandbox removals

Answer (score -1):

May be you can completely uninstall TeamViewer and reinstall back. You try to use uninstall app such as [App Cleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)